# How to sum variable ranges in a pandas column to another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm relatively new to pandas and I don't know the best approach to solve my problem.
Well, I have a df with: an index, and the data in a column called 'Data' and an empty column called 'sum'.

I need help to create a function to add the sum of the variable group of rows of the 'Data' column in the column 'sum'. The grouping criteria is that there should not be empty rows in the group.

Here an example:

```
index  Data Sum
0       1   
1       1   2
2       
3       
4       1   
5       1   
6       1   3
7       
8       1   
9       1   2
10      
11      1   
12      1   
13      1   
14      1   
15      1   5   
16  
17      1   1
18  
19      1   1
20
```

As you see, the length of each group of data in 'Data' is variable, could be only one row or any number of rows. Always the sum must be at the end of the group. As an example: the sum of the group of rows 4,5,6 of the 'Data' column should be at row 6 in the 'sum' column.

any insight will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The problem was solved by implementing the Method 3 suggested by ansev. However due to a change in the main program, the sum of each block, now need to be at the beggining of each one (in case the block has more than one row). Then I use the `df = df.iloc[::-1]` instruction twice in order to reverse the column and back again to normal.   Thank you very much!!!!!

```
df = df.iloc[::-1]
blocks = df['Data'].isnull().cumsum()
m = blocks.duplicated(keep='last')
df['Sum'] = df.groupby(blocks)['Data'].cumsum().mask(m)
df = df.iloc[::-1]

print(df)

Data  Sum
0    1.0  2.0
1    1.0  NaN
2    NaN  NaN
3    NaN  NaN
4    1.0  3.0
5    1.0  NaN
6    1.0  NaN
7    NaN  NaN
8    1.0  2.0
9    1.0  NaN
10   NaN  NaN
11   1.0  5.0
12   1.0  NaN
13   1.0  NaN
14   1.0  NaN
15   1.0  NaN
16   NaN  NaN
17   1.0  1.0
18   NaN  NaN
19   1.0  1.0
20   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Have you made any inroads into the code?

Comment: You'd want to start by making a column that explicitly states which group each row is in. Then you can use df.groupby('group').sum() to add up the Data in each group and then join it back into the dataframe using df = df.join( sum, on='group').

Comment: You mean `NaN` columns, right? There are no "_empty_" columns in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
# if you need replace blanks
#df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
s = df['Data'].isnull()
df['sum'] = df.groupby(s.cumsum())['Data'].cumsum().where((~s) & (s.shift(-1)))
print(df)
    index  Data  sum
0       0   1.0  NaN
1       1   1.0  2.0
2       2   NaN  NaN
3       3   NaN  NaN
4       4   1.0  NaN
5       5   1.0  NaN
6       6   1.0  3.0
7       7   NaN  NaN
8       8   1.0  NaN
9       9   1.0  2.0
10     10   NaN  NaN
11     11   1.0  NaN
12     12   1.0  NaN
13     13   1.0  NaN
14     14   1.0  NaN
15     15   1.0  5.0
16     16   NaN  NaN
17     17   1.0  1.0
18     18   NaN  NaN
19     19   1.0  1.0
20     20   NaN  NaN
```

---

**Method 2**

```
#df = df.drop(columns='index') #if neccesary
g = df.reset_index().groupby(df['Data'].isnull().cumsum())
df['sum'] = g['Data'].cumsum().where(lambda x: x.index == g['index'].transform('idxmax'))
```

**Method 3**

[`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
blocks = df['Data'].isnull().cumsum()
m = blocks.duplicated(keep='last')
df['sum'] = df.groupby(blocks)['Data'].cumsum().mask(m)
```

as you can see the methods only differ in the way of masking the values ​​we don't need from the `sum` column.

We can also use `.transform('sum')` instead `.cumsum()`

**performance with the sample dataframe**

```
%%timeit
s = df['Data'].isnull()
df['sum'] = df.groupby(s.cumsum())['Data'].cumsum().where((~s) & (s.shift(-1)))
4.52 ms ± 901 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
g = df.reset_index().groupby(df['Data'].isnull().cumsum())
df['sum'] = g['Data'].cumsum().where(lambda x: x.index == g['index'].transform('idxmax'))
8.52 ms ± 1.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
blocks = df['Data'].isnull().cumsum()
m = blocks.duplicated(keep='last')
df['sum'] = df.groupby(blocks)['Data'].cumsum().mask(m)
3.02 ms ± 172 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Hi, what's going on this part . `.where((~s) & (s.shift(-1)))`? What is it accomplishing?

Comment: this puts in NaN the values ​​of the column `Sum` that are not in the last cell of the group. You can check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html

Comment: @ansev Would there be a way to use df.groupby.last() to somehow answer this question after calculating cumsums. I am attempting it, but my Pandas skills are weak.

Comment: Nice!  Which is fastest?

Comment: They all have similar returns, it depends on the number of rows, columns and groups. I think I would use method 3 @ScottBoston

Comment: @ansev Hi ansev. Thank you for your answer.  I've gone over a logic a bit more but it seems that `(~s)` is not needed?
s.shift(-1) returns true to only last values of a group, unless we have consecutive  `nans` which will just result in a `nan` value if true under `where` condition which we don't mind. I am assuming the `~s` is an extra layer of precaution? Is there a case you know of where just shift(-1) fails? Running your code with shift(-1) seems to work, unless I missed something.

Comment: you're right! It is not necessary. if we used `. transform ('sum')`  that would be necessary unless we specified `min_count = 1`,  `.transform (lambda x: x.sum (min_count = 1))`. On the other hand I have noticed that this method fails when there are no missing values!,  I would use method 3!

Answer (score 1):

Code Used for replication

```py
import numpy as np
data = {'Data':  [1,1, np.nan , np.nan,1, 1, 1,np.nan , 1,1,np.nan,1,1,1,1,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame (data)
```

Iterative Approach Solution

```py
count = 0
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df.iloc[i, 0] == 1:
        count += 1
    elif i != 0 and count != 0:
        df.at[i - 1, 'Sum'] = count
        print(count)
        count = 0
```

Comment: `df.shape[0]` is always better than `len(df)`.

Comment: ``df.shape[0] is always better than len(df)`` - is this because of the speed or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column that is equal to the index in the data gaps and undefined, otherwise:

```
df.loc[:, 'Sum'] = np.where(df.Data.isnull(), df.index, np.nan)
```

Fill the column backward, count the lengths of the identically labeled spans, redefine the column:

```
df.Sum = df.groupby(df.Sum.bfill()).count()
```

Align the new column with the original data:

```
df.Sum = df.Sum.shift(-1)
```

Eliminate 0-length spans:

```
df.loc[df.Sum == 0, 'Sum'] = np.nan
```